# How to change the Graphical parameters in Panel Function for xyplot in R

Tags: r

Any ideas about how to change the color, line width and other Graphical parameters in Panel Function for `xyplot`? I was trying use `col` and `panel.col`, did not work.

```
library(lattice)
xyplot(F(X) ~ X, 
   panel = function(x, y) {
   panel.xyplot(x, y)
   panel.abline(lm(y ~ x))
   }, 
   xlab = "x (%)", 
   ylab = "y (%)")
```

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. What colors are you trying to change here in particular? It would be nice to provide data so we can actually run and test the code.

Comment: Please be specific: where does `xyplot` come from? `lattice`?

Comment: @camille Yes, thanks.

Comment: there are several ways to do this in lattice but perhaps it is enough to do ...`panel.xyplot(x, y, pch=16, col="red") ;    panel.abline(lm(y ~ x), lwd=3, col="blue")` etc